# Send SMS to self and receive it

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I'm building an android app, and I would like to send a sms to the current user, and then read the content of this sms with a BroadcastReceiver. At the moment the sms is successfully sent, but my BroadcastReceiver is not working.
I did put the right permissions in manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Here is the code of my Fragment :

```
public class GetOtpFragment extends Fragment {

    private SMSReceiver mSMSreceiver;
    private VerificationActivity mActivity;
    private EditText mPhoneNumber;
    private Button mVerifyButton;

    public GetOtpFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActivity = (VerificationActivity) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_get_otp, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        mPhoneNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        mVerifyButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.verify_phone_number_button);

        // I register my receiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        mSMSreceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        mActivity.registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, intentFilter);

        // verify phone number
        mVerifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // this works
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(mPhoneNumber.getText().toString(), null, "test", null, null);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mActivity.unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
    }
}
```

And my BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // never called
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.d("---- smsreceiver ---", "in smsreceiver");

    }
}
```

So like I said, the sms is really sent, I can find it in the sms app, but there is no notification. The thing is that my receiver is never called, there are no log and no toast, and I don't know why. Is it because `sendTextMessage` doesn't create any notification ?

Comment: "Is it because `sendTextMessage` doesn't create any notification ?" - None of `SmsManager`'s methods create `Notification`s. Apps themselves are responsible for issuing those. You should at least be getting a `Notification` for the incoming message, if you haven't disabled them in your SMS app. Are you sure you have the right number? Can you successfully send yourself a message from the SMS app? Are you seeing the outgoing, or the incoming message in your SMS app? What version of Android, and what kind of device are you testing on?

Comment: Right now I'm using a virtual device with android studio. So yes, when I send the messsage, there is no notification for the incoming message. But after when I go in the sms app, the message is really here. The thing is my BroadcastReceiver doesn't catch sms sent with `sendTextMessage`, but catch other sms, I don't understand.

Comment: If you're seeing the outgoing message in the SMS app, then it is getting sent, and you're running on API 4.4 or above, so the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast cannot be aborted. This, along with the fact that you're not getting the incoming message or the `Notification` for it, would most likely mean that you're not sending to the correct number for the emulator. I'm not sure how emulators handle that, though, as I only test SMS on actual devices. If your Receiver works for other incoming messages, then I'd say you're probably OK. Can you test sending to yourself on a real device?

Comment: Yeah I know why, this is because I try to do it with the virtual device, this is the problem. But the thing is I don't manage to launch my app on a real device, this is strange

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "I don't manage to launch my app on a real device".

Comment: When I try to launch the activity on a real device, there is lots of logs in the android monitor, it never stops, and the activity never launch. The gradle build works well, it's only at the moment of launching the activity on the real device. I don't know if it's clear ahah

Comment: Dunno. That could be any number of things. Try to figure out what the logs are telling you. This wouldn't be directly related to the SMS send, though, 'cause you're not even getting that far.

Comment: Yeah I will investigate. I can run on any virtual device but I tried on different real devices and it doesn't work. I will take a look. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try registering to the intent on the manifest, instead of registering programatically and see if you are then able to receive the broadcast.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.SMSReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If that doesn't work it might be because some other app catches the broadcast before you do, and consumes it (as the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast is an ordered broadcast), if that's the case try adding `android:priority="2147483000"` to the intent-filter like so:

```
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

If it did work, you might have a problem with the `registerReceiver`, make sure you're activity stays live until the sms is received back.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried to registering the receiver in the manifest like you said, but it didn't work. With the priority it didn't work either. Why ahah ?